# Google Marketplace domain application data access/revoke

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am not sure how to correctly handle Google domain application access/revoke. Situation is quite standard:

- domain admin installs an application through marketplace workflow (scopes, setup url, ...)
- application is than listed in admin console for domain (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#AppsList:serviceType=MARKETPLACE)
- everything works fine, users can access app
- at some moment, for some reason admin revokes application data access through the admin console for whatever reason (application is not deleted, only "disabled")
- since than, as there is no privilege granted for app in domain, every user who accesses the application is redirected to error page

And here comes the question - how to properly detect and handle this. As some Google docs say, app should re-request required privileges through consent screen (approval force param).
But as my tests show - when user (admin or non-admin) accepts scopes needed on consent screen, application on admin console is still displayed with no data access.
But the same application is instead listed in user's connected apps (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions), even it is domain-installable app!

So do I programmatically handle this situation. Is there a way, or should I just redirect (admin)user to admin console to manually turn data access for that application on?

BTW, after marketplace installation, "sometimes" another consent screen pops up first time visiting app url - which obviously requests same scopes as marketplace listing - why is that?
On that case, application is dually listed like in previous case - in domain and in user's connected apps.